# Requiring $\lVert v\rVert=1$ in the definition of $D_vf(X)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definition

Why does the definition of directional derivative require that the length of the vector in the direction of which the derivative is taken be $1$?

Here's a problem that I see with this. Suppose $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable (say everywhere). Then if $v=e_1+e_2$, then  $$D_{v}f(X)=f'(X)(v)=f'(X)(e_1)+f'(X)(e_2)=D_{e_1}f(X)+D_{e_2}f(X)$$

There's no problem with $D_{e_i}f(X)$ since $e_i$ have unit length. But $v$ doesn't have unit length. Then shouldn't $D_vf(X)$ be undefined? But it is defined, since it's equal to $f'(X)(v)$...

Comment: the only important of the direction vector is, indeed, the direction. Thats why you don't care the modulus of that vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can always normalize the vector, that is, use $\frac 1{\sqrt{2}} (e_1 + e_2)$ instead.

We use unit vectors, so that the derivative gives a consistent picture of how the function changes around the point when we look in different directions. We could define the derivative in the direction of the vector $\frac 1n e_1$ and then it's just a rescaled version of the standard partial derivative:
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x + h\frac 1n e_1) - f(x)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x + h\frac 1n e_1) - f(x)}{\frac hn}\cdot n = nD_{e_1}f(x).$$